# почему true?

Tags: типы, visual-c++, алгоритм, c++, if

if (((n+k/100)==(k/n)))

почему эта ветка выдает 1, при k=10,n=3.

ведь 3+10/100=3,1

```
  а 10/3=3,333333
```

если не ошибаюсь, то у с++ по умолчанию точность именно 6 знаков после запятой.

// k,n-int

Comment: Вы не вполне правы насчёт точности. Значения с плавающей точкой [по умолчанию double](http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/floating_literal), до 6 знаков после запятой обрезается, судя по всему, при выводе.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Потому что если все операнды - целые числа, то и результат всегда - целое число. Возможная дробная часть при этом отсекается.

Answer (score -1):

```
if ((((double)n+(double)k/100.0)==((double)k/(double)n)))
```

Comment: И что бы это значило? Если такое производить с рациональными числами, то нормально, а вот c double/float таких фокусов лучше не делать. На экзамене за такое надо сразу оценку снижать.

Comment: Вот-вот. Сравнение чисел с плавающей запятой - тот еще фокус. За такое оценку снижают не только на экзамене.

Comment: предложите свой вариант

Comment: Вариант чего? Сравнения двух результатов? `fabs(a - b) < eps`, а значение eps -- желательная точность.

Comment: Ваш код отличается по смыслу от кода ТС! У него `n + (k/100)`, а у вас `(n + k)/100.0`.

Comment: Можно воспользоваться неявным приведением типа правого операнда к типу левого (т. н. *integral promotion*) и уменьшить количество `(double)`-ов: `if (((1.0 / 100.0) * k + n) == ((double)k / n)))`.